# Confusion of annotating generator function as iterator

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-typing

In the Python [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) documentation it is written:

> Alternatively, annotate your generator as having a return type of either Iterable[YieldType] or Iterator[YieldType]:

```
def infinite_stream(start: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    while True:
        yield start
        start += 1
```

I wrote a very easy example of printing an infinite stream. I have a generator function which is passed to another function and then called.

```
from typing import Iterator


def infinite_stream(start: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    while True:
        yield start
        start += 1


def print_infinite_stream(inf_iterator: Iterator[int]):
    for x in inf_iterator(5):
        print(x)


print_infinite_stream(infinite_stream)
```

With mypy I get two errors:

- error:Iterator[int] not callable
- error:Argument 1 to "print_infinite_stream" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], Iterator[int]]"; expected "Iterator[int]"

I am confused why i am getting these errors as i worked according to the documentation and have the latest python (3.6.5) and mypy (0.590) installed. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> annotate your generator as having a return type of either Iterable[YieldType] or Iterator[YieldType]

Generator functions return generators, they are not generators themselves. If you do:

`reveal_type(infinite_stream)`, you will get something like `Callable[[int], Iterator[int]]`.

What you want is the return value of the function, the actual iterator.

```
from typing import Iterator


def infinite_stream(start: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    while True:
        yield start
        start += 1


def print_infinite_stream(inf_iterator: Iterator[int]):
    for x in inf_iterator:
        print(x)


print_infinite_stream(infinite_stream(5))
```

This makes more sense as now `print_infinite_stream` handles *any* iterator, not just your generator function. If you `reveal_type(infinite_stream(5))` you should get something like `Iterator[int]`, which is exactly what you want.